# Why package name is using project name?

Tags: uwp, package, windows-10, installation, appxmanifest

I have a uwp project, the project name is FirstMobile, in Package.appxmanifest, I click Packaging and put package name as WinTest, then I click Store--> Add to generate intall appx file, but why the generated appx is name as FirstMobileXXXXX, why it is not WinTest? After I install it, the install location is WinTestXXXXX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could view your manifest file in code:

[image]

What you have changed is the Package Display Name in `VisualElements`, which is how your app name is displayed on user's device. See the `Attributes` in **[Visual Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-visualelements#attributes-and-elements)**:

> A friendly name for the app that can be displayed to users. This string is localizable;

While the `DisplayName` in `Properties` is the name of your app that you reserve in the Store, for apps which are uploaded to the Store.